# Loop to replace values

Tags: loops, replace, stata

I have 343 observations and am trying the following:

```
forvalues in 1/343 {
    replace `ido'="BRA" if `v2'=="F_3idoXidd_2_*"
    replace `ido'="AUS" if `v2'=="F_3idoXidd_3_*"
}
```

The `*` in `F_3idoXidd_2_*` is because I have 30 observations for each country, so I want to do all in one time.

Comment: Note that `forvalues in 1/343` is illegal: it's a mishmash of `foreach` and `forvalues` that isn't legal for either. `forvalues i = 1/343` would be legal. As @ander2ed notes, no loop is needed for your problem, but the record should include that correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't need a loop to replace values of variables. In general, loops in Stata are not used to iterate over observations, but rather lists of some sort (varlist, numlist, etc.).

Also, your use of the wildcard won't function as you expect. Wildcards would also typically be used when specifying a varlist (`drop var*`, `sum gdp*`, etc.).

What you can do here instead is use `strpos` to search for the specified string in the variable, and replace its value conditional on the result of `strpos`. Example:

```
/* Create sample data */
clear *
input str15 v2
"F_03idoXidd_3_3"
"F_03idoXidd_2_3"
"F_03idoXidd_3_2"
"F_03idoXidd_2_2"
end
expand 50
gen ido = ""

replace ido = "AUS" if strpos(v2,"F_03idoXidd_3_")
replace ido = "BRA" if strpos(v2,"F_03idoXidd_2_")
```

or, a one line solution:

```
replace ido = cond(strpos(v2,"F_03idoXidd_3_"), "AUS", cond(strpos(v2,"F_03idoXidd_2_"),"BRA",""))
```

`strpos` returns 0 if the specified string is not found, and the position which it is first found otherwise. Used following the `if` qualifier, it is evaluated as true if > 0, and false otherwise. In this case, you could search v2 for `F_3idoXidd_3_` and `replace` with `AUS`.

Of course this is just one approach and might not be ideal if you have many replacement values.

## EDIT

Based on the comments to this answer, OP needs to create a second variable conditional on the value of the last integer in the string.

One method to do this relies on `substr` and assumes the `F_3idoXidd_` portion of the string does not change across observations in such a way that different values (for example, `F_4idoXidd_3_2`) would have a different meaning than `F_3idoXidd_3_2`.

```
gen idd = ""
replace idd = "AUS" if substr(v2, -2,.) == "_3"
replace idd = "BRA" if substr(v2, -2,.) == "_2"
```

or again, a one line solution using `substr` and `cond`:

```
gen idd = cond(substr(v2,-2,.) == "_3", "AUS", cond(substr(v2,-2,.) == "_2", "BRA",""))
```

Again, this is only one way which springs to mind quickly. You may also be interested in looking at `regexm` and any number of the functions documented at `help string_functions`

Comment: In fact cond and strpos works. But I've F_3idoXidd_2_3 and also need to create idd would F_3idoXidd_*_3 equal "AUS", for example, which was unable to cond and strpos.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If every value of `v2` beginning `F_3idoXidd_2_` should map to `BRA`, and every value of `v2` beginning `F_3idoXidd_3_` should map to `AUS` (as your question suggests) then I see no issue. Is that not actually the pattern you are working with? `F_3idoXidd_*_3` is completely different than `F_3idoXidd_3_*`.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I understand your question. You need a second variable, `idd` created in a similar fashion? There could be multiple approaches to that. Does the `F_3idoXidd_` portion change or only the numbers following it near the end of the string?

Comment: F_3idoXidd_2_ to BRA and F_3idoXidd_3_ to AUS to indicate the country of origin. But in fact I have F_3idoXidd_2_3 in the last number indicates the destination country. So I have to create a variable ido (origin) and other idd (destination).

Comment: See edits to answer. If this doesn't work, then you will need to edit more information into your question about what exactly you need to do, sample data that we can use to reproduce the issue, and a clear explanation of the desired result.